# What happens if I blame The Powers That Be?

Tags: tropico-4

Near the end of second scenario, "It's All Mine!", I tried to rescue those trapped by the earthquake with the Chinese drill, but the faulty drill blew up. Then I had to choose someone to blame for it. One of the options was "Blame The Powers That Be", but it didn't say what will happen if I pick that. I was intrigued by it, but scared what might happen to me. What could've happened?

Comment: Presumably the Religious faction would not have appreciated it, although it may also have driven people to leave that faction.  I haven't gotten to start playing that scenario yet though...

Comment: @bwarner: Maybe, but the others stated it clearly: "-30 with Chinese" and "-10 respect", but it said something like "unknown effect"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it tonight, and it didn't seem to have any direct effect (Maybe it's random?).  However, the Chinese were very happy that I didn't blame them, and I got something like a +50 boost from them.

Comment: its possible the chances of you suffering a random global event such as a hurricane has increased, but you'll never know

Comment: I will try it and post my results also. Hopefully I'll get there in the next day or two.  >.>

Comment: I tried it. I also got a message from China thanking me, but to no obvious gain. I also noticed 3 earthquakes in rapid secession immediately after, but that may have been a coincidence.

Comment: I got another earthquake. Seems the 'Power That Was' was not happy with me blaming him! But like in the answer, I got a good boost from the Chinese.